Transaction error WalletSendTransactionError Unexpected error
this is my code,I made a transaction but it gave me an error as below.
  const [sleeperPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("sleeper_account"), account.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  const [tokenAccount] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("token_account"), account.toBuffer(), mintAddress.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  const sleeperAccountInstruction = await program.methods
    .createNewSleeper()
    .accountsPartial({
      sleeperAccount: sleeperPDA,
      tokenAccount: tokenAccount,
      payer: account,
      mint: mintAddress,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      rent: new PublicKey("SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111"),
      tokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .instruction();

  const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  const transaction = new Transaction({
    blockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
    feePayer: account,
    lastValidBlockHeight: blockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
  }).add(sleeperAccountInstruction)

  console.log(transaction);

  try {
    const response: ActionPostResponse = await createPostResponse({
      fields: {
        type: "transaction",
        transaction: transaction,
      },
    });

    return Response.json(response, { headers });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    let message = "An unknown error occurred";
    if (typeof err == "string") message = err;
    return new Response(message, {
      status: 400,
      headers,
    });
  }


log transaction

Transaction {
  signatures: [],
  feePayer: PublicKey [PublicKey(Ci4oN3oLbaQLUpvbFuDmkW1347yJCkB7mdX8B62KnYQr)] {
    _bn: <BN: adf5aa51ea015a3938d9a19e956ff2b89fd96b3dae6ec70df1bf060788fae1cb>
  },
  instructions: [
    TransactionInstruction {
      keys: [Array],
      programId: [PublicKey [PublicKey(13go66PaZfF5vMYAKhvq5tRbcAmcEEiS8eLeqJnwkokF)]],
      data: <Buffer 6e 5f bd fd 6e 9d 22 0d>
    }
  ],
  recentBlockhash: '8XtFzTHiiVS6HFhuuhTQZxBxuBAjSvgmzVEoy91RsxGh',
  lastValidBlockHeight: 324743181,
  nonceInfo: undefined,
  minNonceContextSlot: undefined,
  _message: undefined,
  _json: undefined
}


rust
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitSleeper<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        space = 8 + Sleeper::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [b"sleeper_account".as_ref(), payer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub sleeper_account: Account<'info, Sleeper>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = token_account,
        seeds= [b"token_account".as_ref(), payer.key().as_ref(), mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    // pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}


Could you maybe log the transaction and add that to your question? console.log("Transaction Signature:", tx);
Also how are you calling that transaction? In a test? In the web? Can you add your client code as well please?

@JonasH. i added, this is code in api nextjs and  i'm doing blinks action

Oh i havent used blinks yet.

whether i use blink or front end it still fails

Error: AnchorError caused by account: sleeper_account. Error Code: ConstraintSpace. Error Number: 2019. Error Message: A space constraint was violated.
Program log: Left: 90
Program log: Right: 162

this error when run in front end, i updated rust code

how does the sleeper struct look like? If there is dynamic data in it INIT_SPACE would not work properly. You may need to limit strings and arrays: See an example here: https://github.com/solana-developers/developer-bootcamp-2024/blob/main/project-1-favorites/programs/favorites/src/lib.rs

thank you i will check it out
